# How to know form submit sucessfully in yii

Tags: yii

i want to submit button disable when form submitted sucessfully, because user click submit button so many times when page loading so its saved the same records so many times.so i want to decided to when form submit sucessfully mean disable that submit button.i am also using aftervalidate function but it can't correct form submit successfull.

My Coding:

```
 <?php
 $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
     'id' => 'question-form',
     // Please note: When you enable ajax validation, make sure the corresponding
     // controller action is handling ajax validation correctly.
     // There is a call to performAjaxValidation() commented in generated controller code.
     // See class documentation of CActiveForm for details on this.
     'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
     'enableClientValidation' => false,
     'clientOptions' => array(
         'validateOnSubmit' => true,
         'validateOnChange' => false,
         'afterValidate' => 'js:buttondisable',

     ),
 ));
 ?>
 <div class="form-group">
     <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'question_title'); ?>
     <?php echo $form->textField($model, 'question_title', array('size' => 50, 'maxlength' => 250, 'class' => 'form-control')); ?>
     <?php echo $form->error($model, 'question_title'); ?>
 </div>
 <?php if ($tileAssigned == Yii::app()->const->FLAG_ZERO) { ?>
 <div class="form-group">
     <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'type', array('label' => 'Is Multiple Choice')); ?>
     <?php echo $form->radioButtonList($model, 'type', $yesnoList, array('separator' => '', 'onchange' => 'questionTypeChange(this.value);', 'class' => '')); ?>
     <?php echo $form->error($model, 'type'); ?>
 </div>
```

But After validation function calling when validation done in every time,but i want to form submit sucessfully at this time disable button.

Comment: When you click on submit button, you can disable immediately it to avoid multple clicks.

Comment: once all validation fine mean i can disable immediately.but how i know all validation fine,i am enable ajax validation so page not loading any validation error having form.once i write button disable function in click submit button after that validation error msg it show that button disable only na

Comment: I think that you could get info listening to 'submit' event: $('#form').on('submit', function() { .... });

Comment: $('#form').on('submit', function() { .... }); it also calling every time when form submit and having validation error in page.i want call function when page having no validation error once no validation error mean at this time call function,

Comment: Maybe you could use $.fn.yiiactiveform.afterValidation // function (form, data, hasError) | boolean

Comment: Ya aftervalidation(e(form,data,hasError){if(!hasError){}else{}} its working thanq